# Getting the current row number?

Tags: vi, vim

Is there any key mapping that outputs the current row number of the line being edited? Or, even better yet, can we do formulas based on the output of the key mapping?

I want to get the row number and add `1` to the current text being edited.

Comment: output means "text of my document"

Comment: Are you trying to display a result, or are you trying to write that result into the buffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was given by @ZyX in a comment to another answer:

> You have `<C-r>` in insert mode for this kind of things:
>
> `nnoremap <F1> i<C-r>=line('.')+1<CR><Esc>`

Answer (score 55):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will tell you the line number and even the column the cursor is in.  If you mean output it as text to your document, then not that I know of.

Comment: ctrl+G to me only shows the total number of lines and the /percentage/ of the document i'm in... crazy. vim 7.1

Answer (score 54):

What do you mean by "output"?  You can do:

```
:echo line(".") + 1
```

To display the current line number plus 1.  You can bind a keystroke with `map`, eg:

```
:noremap <F1> :echo line(".") + 1<cr>
```

To actually insert the data into the buffer:

```
:noremap <F1> :execute "normal! i" . ( line(".") + 1 )<cr>
```

Comment: You must not use `:map` here. Without `nore` [no `*map` commands should be used at all](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html), but additionally `:map` defines mapping for more modes than you would like to see in: you don’t need these mappings in visual (they won’t work here at all) and operator-pending modes. Also using `:normal` is strange, you have `<C-r>` in insert mode for this kind of things: `nnoremap <F1> i<C-r>=line('.')+1<CR><Esc>`.

Comment: Thank you nnoremap <F1> i<C-r>=line('.')+1<CR><Esc> is the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 12):

### 1. Use `:set ruler`. (Works only in `vim`) [Reference](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'ruler')

It shows the current line and column of the line being edited (line where the cursor lies), at the bottom right corner of the widow.

`1,1     <position>`

1. If first line is edited, position is `Top`.
2. If last line is edited, position is `Bot`.
3. If no scroll is available (both start and end lines are visible), position is `All`
4. If no first and last lines are visible, position is the percentage of the document visible.

To make it permanent, add `set ruler` in `~/.vimrc` file (if file is not there, create one).

### 2. Use `:set number`. (Works in both `vi` and `vim`) [Reference](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'number')

Displays the line number before every line.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the visual width of the current cursor position with `virtcol('.')`; insert that into the buffer through the expression register, e.g. in insert mode with `<C-R>=virtcol('.')<CR>`

Note that the width is different from the number of characters when the line contains double-width characters, `<Tab>` or unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

not really related to original problem, but for me, to see a line number I prefer use `:#`, it will print out the line number and content as well

Comment: Works on Vi Version SRV4.0 Solaris 2.5.0 (an old version of solaris). No idea if it works on the current versions.